# RMI: object from server with reference as UnicastRemoteObject

Tags: java, rmi

I am not experienced in RMI and I have found some code in internet about which I am not sure. So there are rmi client and rmi server.

```
public class RmiServer{
  public Wrapper getWrapper(){
      return new Wrapper(new Foo());
  }
}

public class Wrapper implements Serializable{
  private FooI foo;
  public Wrapper(FooI foo){
   this.foo=foo;
  }
  public void doIt(){
   foo.doIt();
  }
}

public interface FooI extends Remote{
  public void doIt();
}

public class Foo implements FooI{
 public void doIt(){...}
 public Foo(){
   //PLEASE, PAY ATTENTION TO THIS LINE
   UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 8888);
 }
}
```

I explain this code to myself this way. `Wrapper` class is serializable and that is why its object is transfered to `RmiClient` from `RmiServer` (on getWrapper()). `Foo` implements `Remote` interface and its object is not transfered to `RmiClient`, instead of this reference to `UnicastRemoteObject` is transfered. So when on client side `Wrapper.doIt()` is called then on server side `Foo.doIt()` is called. Is this right? If not, how to explain this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all completely pointless. An exported remote object is already serialized as its stub. Stubs are already Serializable. The wrapper class is adding nothing useful here. Throw it away and just use the stub directly.

The line you want us to pay attention to merely exports the remote object. There's nothing startling about it.

> So when on client side `Wrapper.doIt()` is called then on server side `Foo.doIt()` is called.

`Wrapper.doIt()` calls `foo.doIt()`, which executes `Foo.doIt()` at the server. However the same thing would have happened if the client had called `foo.doIt()` directly. That is exactly what RMI already does.

> Is this right?

Yes.

> If not, how to explain this solution?

I can't explain it. Somebody has added a pointless wrapper class. Do not imitate.